# Visual Basic - Selection start / end position

Tags: vba

im currently stuck on a problem with visual basic. I need to get the start and the end of the selection, in the example on the image it should be 12/19. Couldnt find anything on the internet.. I guess im just to stupid... Hope you can help me

[image: Window]

Comment: What program is this for?

Comment: More like what control is that ? It seems more like TextBox in VB.Net than form control in VBA.

Comment: It reads a txt and writes a ini with start and end positions of attributes for example the output in the ini should look like the following: PNR= 12,19

Comment: There is no "selection" when reading a textfile. I assume you are reading the file into a textbox (in Access, in excel, in some other program automated by VBA?) and the user makes their selection then clicks a button? Sorry, but to be helpful there are a lot of blanks you're going to need to fill in for us.

Comment: If this is a `TextBox` control, just use the `SelStart`, `SelLength` and `SelText` properties.

Comment: Yeah sorry, There is a Vb Form with a TextBox. I read Data from a data.txt file and put it inside the text box with  the dataBox.appendText(reader.ReadLine) command. After this i make a selection with my mouse and want to get the start and position of my selection, in this example it should be 12 and 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear from the question, but it *looks* like a `TextBox` control on a UserForm. If that's the case, then you can get the start and end of the current selection using the `SelStart` and `SelLength` properties:

```
 Dim p1 As Long
 p1 = TextBox1.SelStart

 Dim p2 As Long
 p2 = p1 + TextBox1.SelLength
```

Comment: Thank you guys got it working

Answer (score 0):

If that is a `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` then you can use the selection properties:

```
.SelectionStart 
.SelectionLength
```

Comment: It can't be a `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` if it's VBA...... but looking again, could be that the question is just mistagged.